# Python logging create log file with future date

Tags: python, flask, logging

My log files in the past few month is looking like this:

```
2023-04-05.log
2023-04-06.log
2023-04-07.log.2023-05-13
2023-04-07.log.2023-05-14
2023-04-07.log.2023-05-15
2023-04-07.log.2023-05-16
2023-04-07.log.2023-05-17
2023-04-08.log
2023-04-09.log
2023-04-10.log
2023-04-11.log
2023-04-11.log.2023-04-11
2023-04-12.log
2023-04-12.log.2023-04-12
```

The logger code is as follows:

```
info_file_name = 'info-' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(time.time())) + '.log'
    info_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logs/info/' + info_file_name, when="midnight", backupCount=7,
                                            encoding='utf-8')
    info_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    info_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I used logger for my flask project and the log file keep created in a weird way. At first, I thought it related to the machine time so it's duplicated. But some of the log files are created with the name of the day of last month and than append the current day.
What should I do to make it creating log files as expected (no weird file)?

Comment: What exactly _do_ you expect? You're starting the logger with the file name being a date. The logger won't change that base name when rolling over. Because it does not _understand_ that it's a date. It will _append_ a date to that base name, that's why you get two dates in the name. If you've started an instance on April 7th, then its log file's base name will always be `2023-04-07.log`, because that's what you told the logger the name should be. The logger will then roll over at midnight and append the date, so a month later the rolled over file will be `2023-04-07.log.2023-05-17`…

Comment: @deceze I want it to create a new file when it rolls over instead of using the base name and append a date to it.

Comment: OK, do clarify that in the question. Also, what's the "future date" problem you allude to in the title? Is there some date discrepancy you're wondering about, or just the issue described above?

Comment: @deceze so it means, if my code execution is started on 2023-04-07 and it keeps on running for a month then all the log file after that wil be 2023-04-07.2023-04-08, ... 2023-04-07.2023-05-08...

Comment: Is there any way so that if  my code execution is started on 2023-04-07 and it keeps on running for a month, the next log file will be 2023-04-08.log instead of 2023-04-07.log.2023-04-08?

Comment: Yes, the base name stays the same, and the current date gets appended to each rolled over log. The log name is expected to be something like `debug.log`, not a changing date.

Comment: So, instead of trying to named the file with date, I should set the name to be info.log or error.log?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been confused about this for some days =">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I understand your query. It is working exactly as you specify.

- Create a log called (the date when the program was started).
- Everyday, rename that file to (the date the program was started) plus date suffix.

You pass a string of the date when the program was run into the rotating handler creation. Imagine you had passed in a logfile name like `my-app-log`. In that case, you'd get `my-app-log` each day, and the previous day would be rotated to `my-app-log.previous-date`. That is just how [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler), or any rotating logger works really. If you want a new file name, you probably need to create a new logger instance each day, rather then giving the handler a one-time static string of the current date when the handler creation is called.

Comment: Oh, I understand how it works now. Thank you so much! I've been confused about this for some days =">